# First prime lens for newbie Canon 600D?

Tags: prime, canon-600d

I'm looking to buy a prime lens, and not sure which to get, for the price range I'm looking at (about £75) I can find these two:

- Canon EF 40mm f/2.8 STM Lens
- Canon EF 50mm f/1.8 II Lens

Ikinda want to try my hand a little at street photography, but most pictures I take at the moment are architecture, with some nature and pictures of my friends. I understand the 50mm might be a little too tele for street photography, but I'm not sure..

Any advice that would help me make a better decision?

*P.S.: I thought about a 30mm or 35mm but the prices are a little too steep for me.*

Comment: On the assumption that you already have the 18-55 kit lens, you can easily find out which focal length you prefer. What more guidance do you need than this?

Comment: Check out the Sigma 30mm, excellent glass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The focal length difference is not too significant, although you might have a personal preference for one or the other.

Both lenses weigh about the same and are equally good optically.

The STM Lens is

- more solidly constructed
- has a stepper motor that works better with Video
- is slimmer, so makes a small DSLR potentially pocketable

The 50mm f/1.8 is

- usefully faster
- usually less costly second-hand

If you really want a 35mm or wider lens then I'd advise you to hold off buying a stop-gap, save your pennies, and keep looking for a second hand bargain. Canon's 35mm f/2 EF (the old non-IS, non-USM version) is an excellent lens, and occasionally appears on eBay at a bargain price.

If you can't wait then obviously the 40mm is closest to what you really want.

Comment: STM shouldn't be relevant for the 600D, since you can't autofocus during video anyway (at least not without letting the aperture open up and living with sudden bright flareups).